# How to convert an IntPtr to array of structs

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, intptr, unmanaged-memory

I have an IntPtr which is a pointer to an array of structs, and I'm trying to convert it to the array.

I tried

`Marshal.Copy(srcIntPtr, destIntPtrArray, 0, destIntPtrArray.Length);`

but after doing the copy, I'm not able to convert the IntPtr's inside of the destination array to the desired structure, while I can convert the srcIntPtr to the structure, which of course only gives me the data of the first index.
It looks like after doing the copy, the destination array contains a bunch of broken IntPtr's

I also tried

```
    var size = Marshal.SizeOf(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(myIntPtr));

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        IntPtr iP = new IntPtr(myIntPtr.ToInt64() + i * size);
    
        MyStruct ms =
            (MyStruct ) Marshal.PtrToStructure(iP, typeof(MyStruct ));
    }
```

which doesn't throw any error, but the data of the array of structs that I get out of my source IntPtr are not accurate.

This is the struct that I'm  trying to convert to

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public Categories categories;  
    public Dimensions dimensions;
}



public struct Categories {
    public double d;
    public double c;
    public double b;
    public double a;
}



struct Dimensions {
    public double v;
    public double e;
}
```

I have `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]` on top of the structs, but removing that doesn't break my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the struct.

Comment: Dear @Sean I just edited my question.
the declaration of the structs in the c++ library is identical to the ones in c#. conversion of an `IntPtr` to one single struct can be done without any problem

Comment: To clarify: you've tried Marshall.Copy to an IntPtr[] array and then looped through to Marshal.Copy each item in that IntPtr[] and the structs are broken/incomplete?

Comment: @JacobShanley no, I copied the `IntPtr` into `IntPtr[]` and then looped through that `IntPtr[]` and tried to `Marshal.PtrToStructure` each of them. but it throws an exception at the beginning of the loop and says `Object reference is not set to an object (unknown wrapper)` a null exception basically. shall I update the question?

Comment: Ah, thanks. No need to update, I think it's clear. I personally just needed a little help understanding what you've tried.

Comment: Marshal.ReadIntPtr(myIntPtr) to read the array size is very unlikely to be correct.  There is no hint whatsoever in the question to tell us how to obtain the array size.  Never not a problem with a C array declaration, we can't see any sample C code that reads that same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```csharp
Marshal.ReadIntPtr(myIntPtr)
```

...returns an `IntPtr`, as the name implies.  When passed to `Marshal.SizeOf()`...

```charp
var size = Marshal.SizeOf(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(myIntPtr));
```

...it does *not* return the size of the `MyStruct` to which it points but the size of `IntPtr` for the current process (either 4 or 8 bytes).  To get the unmanaged size of `MyStruct` you need to call `SizeOf()` like this...

```charp
var size = Marshal.SizeOf<MyStruct>();
```

...or this...

```csharp
var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct));
```

Also, the whole point of `IntPtr` is that it is address width-agnostic, yet you are explicitly retrieving it as a `long`...

```csharp
IntPtr iP = new IntPtr(myIntPtr.ToInt64() + i * size);
```

I don't think that will have a negative effect on anything (as opposed to if you called `ToInt32()` in a 64-bit process, which could throw an `OverflowException`), but it would be better to let `IntPtr` handle calculating the pointer to each `MyStruct` element, which you can do like this...

```csharp
IntPtr iP = IntPtr.Add(myIntPtr, i * size);
```

...or simply this...

```csharp
IntPtr iP = myIntPtr + i * size;
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear lance. I really appreciate this answer.